# Elastic search snapshot and restore with type as url

Tags: elasticsearch, remote-backup

I want to take snapshot of an index present in my local, and save the snapshot at some remote location i.e. another machine.
How can I use elastic search snapshot functionality for this?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you checked out the documentation about snapshot and restore? Is it something you already tried from there?

Comment: I have already checked the documentation and taking snapshot at my local machine worked fine.
But the scenario that I am trying is I have two machines, on both machines I have elastic search up. Now I want to take snapshot of an index which is present in my local machine and store that snapshot in a folder of another machine.

Answer (score -1):

On the machine where you want to transfer your snapshot, define a snapshot repository just like you did for the machine where you took the snapshot. For example:

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' -d '{
    "type": "fs",
    "settings": {
        "location": "/mount/restore/my_backup",
        "compress": true
    }
}'
```

Assuming that your snapshot was something like the following:

`PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/my_first_snapshot`

Copy everything from the snapshot directory on the source machine to the `/mount/restore/my_backup` on the destination machine. And then `POST /_snapshot/my_backup/my_first_snapshot/_restore`. This is, also, in the documentation.

UPDATE: as per @EricLandry's comment, it seems there is a way: `url` type repository. I haven't tested it, but it looks promising after the description.

Comment: Thank u for the reply, but i want to do this task on the fly. I do not want to copy the data from my local to the remote machine manually. I want this task to be accomplished as a PUT request. Is it possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. There is no automatic copying feature. You need to copy the files manually.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-snapshots.html#_read_only_url_repository

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to achieve this? Was it with the Read-only URL Repository listed in the link above by Eric?

Comment: An HTTP migration is possible using the _bulk API via a tool like [esm](https://github.com/medcl/esm).